# How can we get our followers data/details from graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any graph API which gives a page's followers detail?If not is there any alternative?I have a Facebook page and i wanted to collect my followers data(user interests,shares etc)

I have tried graph APIs but it gives single users data only.it doest give page followers data unless and untill we know their userids.No way to collect that also.

Comment: what for exactly? and are you talking about followers of a user profile?

Comment: You can not get a list of page followers, and even if you could, you could still not get any data from just any arbitrary user simply based on that they are following your page - each single one would need to grant your app permission first, otherwise you get no info about them at all, because it is simply none of your business.

Comment: @lusc Cool ! Thanks for the reply.I was talking about my pages followers

Comment: @misorude :Ohh fine

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your page follower's data like that, especially not if you refer to followers (compared to fans, which are two different things/objects).

Do do this it would require the user explicitly granting your app the permission to access that info first, but data you mention (user interests for example) had been deprecated and cannot be accessed via the API anymore.